# Lock portrait orientation and switch to landscape - css

Tags: html, css, orientation, landscape-portrait

Is there any CSS method to automatically switch the orientation from portrait to landscape when as soon as a web app loads in a mobile view? Please help

Comment: no css property or method but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation

Answer (score 0):

This would be only possible in standalone applications.